# Reset a scope variable - Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-rootscope

I want to make sure that `isSearchVisible` scope variable will always start on `false` on every page change. How should I implement it?

```js
app.controller('MainController', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.isSearchVisible = false;
});
    
app.controller('ProfileController', function($scope) {
  $scope.isSearchVisible = true;
});
    
app.controller('AboutUsController', function($scope) {

});
```

In every page, the root scope variable `isSearchVisible` is `false` because of `MainController`.

When you enter the profile page (`ProfileController`), the local scope variable is turned to `true`, which is good.

But when you leave this page, the root scope variable changed as well to `true`. There is no separation between `$rootScope` variables and `$scope` variables.

How should I reset `isSearchVisible` to `false` on every page change, unless the controller directly changed it?

Comment: Is `AboutUsController` nested under `ProfileController`?

Comment: try in the config section where you change your routes.

Comment: Because the $scope is prototypically inherited in Angular, your `AboutUsController` gets the `ProfileController`'s $scope, which redefines the `showSearchBlock` field.

Answer (score 0):

add an event listener to the root scope and then do what you want

`$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
   ... 
    check your url if you want to show the search box in that 
    url make $rootScope.showSearchBlock = true
    else make it false. and remove other instances of the 
    $rootScope.showSearchBlock
    put this on your main controller
   ...
 });`

Comment: @MatanYedayev Nice to see you got an answer. Keep up the work

Answer (score 0):

You have to use services to share data:

```
app.factory('shareDataService', function () {   

 var formData = {};

    return {
        getData: function () {
            //You could also return specific attribute of the form data instead
            //of the entire data
            return formData;
        },
        setData: function (newFormData) {
            //You could also set specific attribute of the form data instead
            formData = newFormData
        },
        resetData: function () {
            //To be called when the data stored needs to be discarded
            formData = {};
        }
    };
});
```

Inject and request from each controller from here.